# Is there a jQuery selector that return all descendant that are 'first of type'?

Tags: jquery

For example, consider this markup:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="d1">
         <div>222</div>
         <div>333</div>
      </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
         <div id="d1_1">
          <div>222</div>
         </div>
      </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: I would like to get only the DIVSs "d1" and "d1_1"

Thanks

Comment: I have Edited the sample to better explain what Im looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('td').find('div:first')
```

This says, find the first div in each td.

Just for fun, this would find those NOT the first one:

```
$('td').find('div:not(:first)')
```

See this (slightly modifed) example: http://jsfiddle.net/ezaHU/

I modified it to add text to the second examples td so it would show in the example.

AND just for complete example, if you ONLY have an id on those:

```
$('td').find('div[id]')
```

But I did not think that is what you were aiming for based on the progression of your edits.

Comment: This is not exactly was I was looking for , but your answer directed me to a solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After your edit you want this :

```
$('div:contains("111"):parent');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children)** like:

```
$('td').children('div')
```

See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQKBq/)**

EDIT: Re-reading your question, in case you know all IDs you can also just do:

```
$('#d1, #d1_1')
```